# Python: Removing spaces between punctuation with positive lookahead

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

I am trying to remove the spaces that occur between punctuation characters in a sentence. To illustrate, the dataset has many strings that look like this:

```
 "This is a very nice text : ) : ) ! ! ! ."
```

But I want them to look like this:

```
 "This is a very nice text :):)!!!."
```

I want to do this by using a [RegEx positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but can someone show me how to do this in Python. I now have code but it does exactly the opposite of what I want by adding extra spaces:

```
 string = re.sub('([.,!?()])', r' \1', string)
```

Comment: You aren't using any lookahead in this regex.

Comment: @Norrius: this can be useful, in case a punctuation is both the "look ahead" of one space, and the "look behind" of the next one.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's a good point, I somehow thought OP was trying to lookahead the spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle you could find the space (spaces?) between punctuation characters (that you capture) and substitute the captured punctuation characters only:

```
string = re.sub('([:.,!?()]) ([:.,!?()])', r'\1\2', string)
```

However, this would result in

```
This is a very nice text :) :) !! !.
```

since `re.sub` does not consider *overlapping matches*.

---

Hence, you need to use the zero-width look-ahead and look-behind - they are not counted into the match, so the matched portion is just the space character, that we then substitute to an empty string.

```
string = re.sub('(?<=[:.,!?()]) (?=[:.,!?()])', '', string)
```

with which the result is `'This is a very nice text :):)!!!.'`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex like:

```
(?<=[.:,!?()])\s+(?=[.:,!?()])
```

Here the two parts between brackets are *look behind* and *look ahead*s, that look for punctuations. We then match the `\s+` (one or more spaces part). We can then replace this with the empty string. For example:

```
import re

rgx = re.compile(r'(?<=[.:,!?()])\s+(?=[.:,!?()])')

rgx.sub('', 'This is a very nice text : ) : ) ! ! ! .')
```

This then produces:

```
>>> rgx.sub('', 'This is a very nice text : ) : ) ! ! ! .')
'This is a very nice text :):)!!!.'
```

Comment: @Oliver Please consider accepting the answer if it worked for you (click the grey checkmark on the left).